# what wifi adapter does linux need?

Tags: usb, adapter

Does anyone know what wireless adapter linux needs to work WiFi?  Cause linksys does not work. It brings up a CD and then when I click the cd and its just a bunch of files. So is there another wireless adapter useable?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Linksys is a brand not a device. Try being more specific: State what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried so far, the version of Ubuntu you're running, the name and model number of the product you're trying to get working, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends.**

Most modern cards have drivers for Linux, or work with generic drivers.  Some very new ones do not. If you check a chipset for a specific card on [kernel.org](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers), you can see if any drivers are compatible with it.